# Recording 32-bit audio resolution with WineHQ

Tags: sound, wine

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 LTS, with WineHQ 3.0.3.

I don't know if this is the same inside any other combination but... I discovered that we can record audio with 32-bit resolution with Adobe Audition 1.5 if we change some specific item in the Devices Properties menu of Audition.

The item is on the **Options** Menu, **Device Properties** item, **Wave In** and **Wave Out** tabs.

Look for the item: "**Get 32-bit audio using**".

Then, choice the: **4-byte IEEE float**, option.

It works for me! I can record 32-bit resolution audio so fine!

I think, there is some kind of "bug" with the **4-byte PCM** and the **3-byte Packed PCM** options. Homework to the WineHQ development team.

Comment: You can always give a try to Audacity: https://www.audacityteam.org/ which is Free, open source, cross-platform audio software, Audacity is an easy-to-use, multi-track audio editor and recorder

Comment: Yes! I use Audacity too! But... There still are some Audition functions not present in Audacity, yet.